# Datetime field error in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-concat

I have start time and end time as  fields in my table.what I need is I will pass start time and end time as input parameter and have to retrieve the rows from start date to end date and display it as 10:00-12:00 in a separate field?
I tried this

```
 SELECT res_id, (time(start_time),time(end_time))as open,
       count(start_time)<4 as AM  
 FROM table 
 WHERE date(start_time)>=in_start_time 
       AND date(start_time)<= in_end_time
```

Comment: More sample data and expected result will help;)

Comment: expected result will be res_id,start_time-end_time,count(starttime-endtime)>4 as am